# jInfoVis Visualization: set node color on json data

Tags: javascript, infovis

This newbie question relates to the InfoVis Visualization project.

Whilst the color and other properties of a node can be defined within the JSON data:

```
id: "",  
name: "",  
data: { color:""},
```

I would like to set the color of a node based on another element, say for example the value of "risk":

```
id: "",  
name: "",  
data: { risk:"1"},
```

e.g.

```
if(node.data.risk == "1") {
                  node.setData('color', '#ffcccc');
```

What is the best way to change the color of a node based on the content of data when the JSON is loaded.

update:

have this solution working so far:

```
onBeforePlotNode: function(node)
    {
        if(node.data.risk == '2') 
        {
            node.data.$color = '#ff5050';                  
        }
        if(node.data.risk == '1') 
        {
            node.data.$color = '#ffcccc';                  
        }
        if(node.data.risk == '0') 
        {
            node.data.$color = '#1aff1a';                  
        }
    },
```

however, it **does not render the new colours until one of the nodes is clicked**.

*Follow up question: provided this is a reasonable solution how can the new colors be rendered when the visualisation first loads?*

update:

Code had to be placed at end of page.